# Wait for other view animation end

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have the following layout snippet:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tagContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/commentLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tagContainer" />
```

As you can see, `animateLayoutChanges` is set to `true` on the `LinearLayout`, so when an item is added to it, it animates the addition. This ok, but there are problems with the removal. If i remove an item, the animation still plays well, but the `TextView` below pops up immediately and does not wait for the animation to finish. How can i achieve this, or even better, make the `TextView` animate up synchronized with the `LinearLayout` animation?

Comment: Can you show us the animation code and how you add the animation to the view? There must be animation listener or LayoutTransformation listener, which has events that notify you for the end, during and end of the animation.

Comment: There is no animation code at all. If you specify this property, the framework adds a default fade animation for item addition/removal.

Answer (score 25):

You can retrieve the [LayoutTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setLayoutTransition%28android.animation.LayoutTransition%29) from the view in following way:

```
mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
LayoutTransition layoutTransition = mLinearLayout.getLayoutTransition();
layoutTransition.addTransitionListener(new TransitionListener(){

            @Override
            public void endTransition(LayoutTransition arg0, ViewGroup arg1,
                    View arg2, int arg3) {
                switch(arg2.getId()){
                                //....
                                }
            }

            @Override
            public void startTransition(LayoutTransition transition,
                    ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {
                switch(view.getId()){
                                //....
                                }

            }});
```

Comment: Thanks! How can i tell the `TextView` to stay in position, and go up? ( I understand end that i have to do this in these callbacks, but i do not know how to to this).

Comment: Using callbacks argument you can differentiate whats the type of the transition `int transitionType` denotes these transition (see doc for transition types), you need to implement your own logic, like 
`if(view.getView() == R.id.myView && transitionType==LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING){
  //add/remove the TextView

}`

First of all, Log the order of events that are occuring and their arguments in the callback, and see how they are called, then experiment with your views. :)

Comment: Is there a way to get the progress of the transition?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but a ready-to use code snippet that you may try to examine what is happening.

```
mContainer = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.container);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    mLayoutTransition = mContainer.getLayoutTransition();

    if (mLayoutTransition != null) {
        mLayoutTransition.addTransitionListener(new LayoutTransition.TransitionListener() {

            @Override
            public void startTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {
                Log.d("\n\n startTransition: in "+container+" view "+view+" type "+ descr(transitionType));
            }

            @Override
            public void endTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {
                Log.d("\n\n endTransition: in "+container+" view "+view+" type "+ descr(transitionType));
            }

            String descr(int transitionType) {
                String[] m = new String[]{"CHANGE_APPEARING","CHANGE_DISAPPEARING","APPEARING","DISAPPEARING"};
                return "" + transitionType + ": " + m[transitionType&3] + " changing="+( transitionType&LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For me, the container view is a `LinearLayout` and the event of interest is:

```
public void endTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) { // UI thread
    if (transitionType == LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING) {
        // start 2nd animation, it will be done while another view is moved
    }
}
```