# Reparenting a View in Android not working

Tags: android

So I have code like such:

```
((LinearLayout) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
container.addView(view);
```

Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but that code should remove the view from its current `ViewGroup`, then add it to a new `ViewGroup`

However, the following `exception` is raised:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(31220): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Any ideas on why this could be happening please?

EDIT: This only happens when android:animateLayoutChanges is set to true in the parent's XML tag

Comment: Could it be possible that the child is not being removed until the layout animation showing its removal completes? Give this question a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868404/wait-for-other-view-animation-end

Comment: Yeah, I did some testing and it turns out that the View isn't actually removed for 300ms
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Due to the animation, the View isn't actually removed until the animation finishes, which takes about 300ms

So something like this should work fine (350ms timer just to make sure the animation has finished):

```
((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).removeView(view);
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        container.addView(view);
    }
}, 350);
```

Comment: While it works, it is not fully safe. Better add TransitionListener and remove it on transition end.

Comment: Tested this, but for some reason the "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first." error appears when a listener is used

Comment: maybe the listener event is fired just before the removal... How about disabling the LayoutTransition when reparenting? Or do you really need it there?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work probably because the View has mParent field which is not being reset by calling removeView() on it's parent.

Instead, it.s probably better to inflate a new View.

**Edit** now that you've said about layoutTransition, you can try removing the layoutTransition from ViewParent while removing it. Never tried it myself though.

```
final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
final LayoutTransition transition = parent.getLayoutTransition();
parent.setLayoutTransition(null);
parent.removeView(view);
parent.setLayoutTransition(transition);
newParent.addView(view);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I realised I'd missed a bit of info out - please see my edit

Comment: Solved my issue. Like this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually try casting it to ViewGroup:

```
((ViewGroup) childView.getParent()).removeView(childView);
```

Comment: You are correct, but it's not an answer to a question.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I realised I'd missed a bit of info out - please see my edit