# How to handle the end of layout animation

Tags: android, android-layout

My layout with `animateLayoutChanges` look like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <Button
        layout_width="wrap_content"
        layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to handle the moment when `setVisibility` aniamtion is eneded:

```
buttom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

How to do it?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17869028/905349).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably use `LayoutTransition` and its listener

```
LayoutTransition mainLayoutTransition = mainLayout.getLayoutTransition();
mainLayoutTransition.addTransitionListener(new TransitionListener(){

    @Override
    public void endTransition(LayoutTransition arg0, ViewGroup arg1,
                    View arg2, int arg3) {
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void startTransition(LayoutTransition transition,
                    ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {

    }
});
```