# Android animateLayoutChanges: can I set a listener?

Tags: android, animation, layout

I have set `android:animateLayoutChanges` to `true` for my `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, I run the following to animate the disappearance of an element.

```
TextView line;
...
line.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

How can I know when the animation has finished?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same question to me,
this post will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17869028

First, get `LayoutTransition` from `LinearLayout` using `getLayoutTransition` method.
Then add `TransitionListener` to layout transition you got.

This method available for api-level `11` and above.

Comment: Is there a way to get the progress of the transition?