# GridLayout is overlapped, when the VISIBILITY of some of its elements is set to GONE

Tags: android, layout, overlapping

I am developing an app on Android with this form :

```
<ScrollView>

  <RelativeLayout>

    <TextView/>

    <RelativeLayout>
      ....
    </RelativeLayout>

    <gridLayout>
      7 CheckBoxes
      1 ImageButton
    </gridLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
      many TextViews
    </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The `ImageButton` inside the `gridLayout` controls when some of the checkBoxes disappear (`VISIBILITY->GONE`) and when it's pressed (the ImageButton) the `LinearLayout`, which is just below it (the gridLayout), overlaps the `gridLayout` before it takes its final form. See the images below :

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6aSc.png This is before the disappearance.
>
> [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHqpj.png This happens during the disappearance.

**EDIT:** The problem happens because the `View.GONE`takes some time to be performed visually, but the `gridLayout`understands that it happens immediately, so it reserves the "empty" space right away. Only think I can figure out, is to set the `View.INVISIBLE` instead and resize the `gridLayout` manually. Is there a better way?

**EDIT2** The problem is caused by `animateLayoutChanges="true"`. Due to the animations, it take some time for the checkBoxes to disappear. Is there a way to force the linearLayout to "wait" for the effect of the animation to end?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to your animation changes of animateLayoutChanges="true" and move the LinearLayout when the animation ends. More information in this thread - [Listner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17869028/3137427)

Also, you can try a combination of `setAlpha(0)` and `setEnabled(false)` on your checkboxes in which case gridLayout won't adjust the views again.